# Tall skinny figure along side of page in LaTeX document?

Tags: latex, figure

Looking for the best way to fit a figure tightly that spans the full height of a page. I'm writing a document about the ionosphere and want to include this image along the side: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermosphere#/media/File:EarthAtmosphereBig.jpg

Seems like a job for minipage but I can't quite figure out a good solution. Any tips?

Comment: Just curious to know, why in SO while there is a dedicated site for LaTeX?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by placing two minipages, one with a larger width than the other, side-by-side.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} %demo option should be omitted in real document
\usepackage{lipsum} %for random text, should be omitted in real document
%--------%Shows page layout, also should be omitted in real document. 
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%--------%Idea from Zarko of TEX.SE

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{0.8\textwidth}
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[r]{0.2\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth, height=\textheight]{demo.png}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]